# python: getting the key value within the value of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to pass the key string into the lambda function as argument for `mn` within the same line. Is there a way to do that? i don't want to retype the key string again.

```
switch = {
    'foo': lambda: bb.Data(ticker=self.ticker, key=self.key, func='yes', mn='foo'),
    'bar': lambda: bb.Data(ticker=self.ticker, key=self.key, mn='bar')
}
```

Comment: thanks. how do I edit it? i'm used to shortcuts in pycharm not sure if there is a shortcut like `ctrl + alt + l`.

Comment: please don't use `bb.Data` in your example. That makes it unnecessarily hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the dictionary like this:

```
switch = {
    key: lambda: do_something(key)
    for key in ['foo', 'bar']
}
```

If you want to call a different function for a different key, you would need something like this:

```
def add_dict_item(a_dict, key):
    if key == 'foo':
        a_dict[key] = lambda: do_something(key)
    elif key == 'bar':
        a_dict[key] = lambda: do_something_else(key)

switch = {}
add_dict_item(switch, 'foo')
add_dict_item(switch, 'bar')
```

Comment: i guess that's ok if the number of arguments are the same. what if they are different?

Comment: What do you mean? I mean which number of arguments?

Comment: You would need an `if` block in your callback which selects a different function call per key. Not sure if that would make the code more readable ...

Comment: Added that to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can define a member function since you have used self. 
And use dictionary comprehension.

```
def mn_func(self, mn_item):
   return bb.Data(ticker=self.ticker, key=self.key, mn=mn_item)

list_of_items = ['foo', 'bar']
switch ={ mn_item:mn_func(mn_item) for mn_item in list_of_items}
```